# Как передать параметры UTM-метки при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: php, html

Возникла необходимость передавать параметры UTM-метки при нажатии на кнопку. 
Знаю, что можно сделать подобное через php с помощью get, но опыта работы с php не было, поэтому куда и что вставлять не сильно понимаю. Сайт на Битрикс.

Спасибо!

Comment: передавать куда?

Comment: @humster_spb в url. Допустим человек переходит на сайт и у него ссылка вида example.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow. Потом он нажимает на ссылку на этой странице и переходит на другой сайт. При этом UTM пропадает. Нужно, чтобы все, что стоит после знака "?" также присутствовало на втором сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если делать на **php**, то нужно формировать ссылку вида:

`<a href="http://newsite.ru?utm_source=<?=$_GET['utm_source'];?>">перейти с utm</a>`

Можно сделать и с помощью **js**. Логика такая:

1. На странице, куда первоначально заходит человек, мы заносим utm в переменную
2. По клику на кнопку отправляем человека по новой ссылке + utm

```js
let utm = window.location.href.split('?').pop(); //получаем utm

document.getElementById('link').onclick = function() { //по клику на кнопку
   window.location = 'http://newsite.ru?'+utm; //переправляем пользователя на новый адрес
}
```

```html
<button id="link">перейти с utm</button>
```

Решение на js изящнее тем, что неважно, сколько параметров в utm. На php придётся вручную прописывать в ссылке `?utm_source=<?=$_GET['utm_source'];?>&utm_campaign=<?=$_GET['utm_campaign'];?>&utm_content=<?=$_GET['utm_content'];?>`

Comment: Спасибо большое!